# mvn clean compile assembly:single works but mvn install or package fails to create jar with dependencies

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven. I am having below pom.xml which creates jar with dependencies perfectly if I use the below cmd:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

But if I use below cmd jar gets created without dependencies.Anything wrong with my pom.xml

`mvn install or mvn package`

```
  <build>
    <finalName>TestProcess</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
         defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                        <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.ge.db.extract.ExtractDBProcess</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                   <executions>
                      <execution>
                       <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                       </execution>
                 </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
     </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39256/add-dependencies-to-maven-pom-xml-file/

Comment: You have to put the part with `maven-assembly-plugin` not in `pluginManagement` just in `plugins` instead under tag `<build>`...

Comment: Do I need to remove plugin managing tags